# Get DataURL from Blob with await

Tags: javascript, data-uri

I have fetch results that I want to turn into a typed [DataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs).

I want to use `await` in the mainline of my app, not callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

### function getDataUrlFromBlob

```
/* 
 * getDataUrlFromBlob
 * Optional: adds content type
 */
async function getDataUrlFromBlob(blob, contentType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            const data = event.target.result;
            resolve(data);
        };
        if (contentType) {
            blob = new Blob([blob], {type: contentType}); // add the type
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
}
```

### Example usage

```
let response = await fetch(url, {method: "GET", mode: "cors"});
if (response && response.ok) {
    const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const dataUrl = await getDataUrlFromBlob(blob, contentType)
    return dataUrl;
}
```